# stuff css, html files to one Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small website which has css, html and javascript file. Is there any framework/tools/workarounds to stuff CSS, html and javascript things into single javascript file.

Comment: Something like webpack?

Comment: No. I don't want to have html and css as separate file, I need everything to be bundled in single javascript file

Comment: You can put CSS and JS in HTML files, in `<style>` and `<script>` tags. You don't put CSS and HTML in JS files.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a javascript bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) or [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/)